# How to take the version in remote branch and forget the change I make in my working directory

Tags: git

I made changes in my working directory and did a 'git commit'

And then I do a 'git pull'. Git tries to pull changes in the remote tracking branch and automatically merge it for me. But there are some files with  conflict.

So How can I just take the version in the remote branch and forget the change I made in a particular file?

I try to do 'git checkout --  chrome/browser/browser.cc', but it said I am in the middle of a merge and it won't let me do it.

```
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       unmerged:   chrome/browser/browser.cc
#       unmerged:   chrome/renderer/render_view.cc
#       unmerged:   chrome/test/automation/automation_proxy_uitest.cc
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `git reset --hard <remote_commit>` would achieve your purpose. This would throw away your local commits and point the HEAD of the current branch at the remote commit.

Also, have you tried `git checkout -f`? That might convince it to do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to completely forget the last commit you made, do a `git reset --hard HEAD^`, which will return your master branch to its previous state - you can also do a `git log`, pick the commit you want to return to, and do `git reset --hard <sha1>`. If, however, other people have pulled the commits you now wish to ignore, it is safer to do a merge with the *ours* strategy, e.g. `git checkout -b temp --track origin/master`, `git merge --strategy=ours master` and `git push`. This will keep the history of the changes you have made, but will remove them from the resulting tree.

If it's just a few files you can of course just choose the fix the conflict by hand, choosing the versions from `origin/master`. Any decent merge tool should allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

to revert your local changes, then just `git pull` your remote changes into the (now) clean local repository.

Comment: That will only revert local, uncommitted changes. It won't work in this case because the local branch has had commits to it. Novelocrat's solution (adding a commit hash instead of HEAD) will solve the problem.